# Grabbing digits at end of URL using PHP

Tags: php

On a page of mine, I have a GET as a URL of a website.

```
mypage.com/page.php?=URLHERE
```

On this URL, I need the ID at the very end of the URL

```
mypage.com/page.php?url=http://www.otherwebsite.com/something.php?id=%%%%%%%
```

These numbers are sometimes different amount of digits, so how would I do that?

My code:

```
  $url = $_GET['url'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the the url has id at the begining of query_string

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = basename($url);
$url =explode("?",$url);
$url = explode("=",$url[1]);
echo $url[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `url` parameter is a properly encoded URL, then use[`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php) to get the URL components and [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.parse-str.php) to retrieve the id parameter from its query string.

```
$url = $_GET['url'];

// First parse_url() breaks the original URL up
$parts = parse_url($url);

// parse_str() parses the query string from the embedded URL
$query = parse_str($parts['query']);

// Finally, you have your full id parameter
$id = $query['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try the [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: this answer would be much much improved by showing an example, but I think it is still a valid answer and not link-_only_.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = parse_url($_GET['url'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
$query = explode('=', $url);
$id = $query[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the PHP function explode() http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

For this example

```
$numbers = explode("=",$url); 
$id_value = $numbers[2];
print $id_value;
```